# Prolog Cryptarithmetic program

Tags: prolog, cryptarithmetic-puzzle

I'm taking a programming course and the professor just lightly skimmed over Prolog due to lack of time.  Anyways, he suggested we research it on our own.  I came across a Cryptarithmetic program that is supposed to calculate? AM+PM = DAY.  I do not know what is supposed to be added as input in the SWI interpreter and what should be received as the correct output...If this makes any sense?

I tried...

```
solve([AM],[PM],[DAY]).
```

That does nothing.  Any help on what the correct input would be for AM+PM = DAY or something similar would be great!  Here is the program I was playing with...

```
solve([A,M,P,D,Y]):-
   select(A,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],WA), % W means Without
   not(A=0),
   select(M,WA,WMA),
   select(P,WMA,WMAP),
   not(P=0),
   select(D,WMAP,WMAPD),
   not(D=0),
   select(Y,WMAPD,WMAPDY),
   DAY is 100*D+10*A+Y,
   AM  is 10*A+M,
   PM  is 10*P+M,
   DAY is AM+PM.
```

Please keep in mind that we only had two classes on Prolog so I know next to nothing!

Scott

Comment: try `solve(X)`, it gives you the possible results for `A`, `M`,`P`,`D` and `Y` in a list of length 5.

Comment: Ok....so that gave me this X = [2, 5, 9, 1, 0].  So what exactly does that mean?  How does that solve AM + PM = DAY?  Prolog is weird!  haha

Comment: try `solve([A, M,P,D,Y]).` hope that helps. It would be easier if you say what you don't understand. Prolog gives you one solution for the problem, if you press <kbd>space</kbd> you'll get the other ones.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Patrick.  I guess I don't understand how the program works.  I figured you input somthing along the lines of AM+PM and it would output DAY.  IM just not sure what the program is expecting for input and what the desired output would be?  Does that make sense?

Comment: Hey, I tried to give you an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this program will give a variable assignment for the formula

```
DAY = AM + PM
```

Where each of the characters is a digit from `0` to `9` no, digit may be used twice and `A`,`P` and `D` mustn't be `0` (no leading zeroes allowed).

For beginners trying to understand prolog programs it might be more feasible to ask the question: "How is it (the program) true", instead of "what input generates which output". Prolog gladly supplies you with the variable settings it needed to make, to give you a `true`. (It also tracks on the way where it could have gone another way, so can ask again).

The program uses pattern matching, but basically wants a list of five elements which represent the variables `A`, `M`,`P`,`D` and `Y` (in that order).

`select`'s arguments are:

1. something (you can put in a list)
2. a list that contains the first argument
3. the list without the first argument.

`not` tries to solve what it is given and fails if it succeeds.

`,` is a short cirquiting and, like `&&` in many C-like languages.

The last four lines are simple arithmetics, while the lines above just ensure that you aren't selecting doubles and leading `0`s.

so after you have loaded your program, you can query for answers:

```
?- solve([A, M,P,D,Y]).
A = 2,
M = 5,
P = 9,
D = 1,
Y = 0
```

If you want another solution, you can hit <kbd>space</kbd> or <kbd>;</kbd>. If you want to know, if there is a solution with `A = 5`, you can query like this:

```
?- A = 5, solve([A, M,P,D,Y]).
A = 5,
M = 6,
P = 9,
D = 1,
Y = 2
```

If you want to "reassemble" it, this line might help:

```
?- solve([A, M,P,D,Y]), format('~w~w~w= ~w~w + ~w~w~n', [D,A,Y,A,M,P,M]).
```

`format` is something like `printf` in many other languages.

Comment: That answered my questions Patrick!  Thanks for being patient and explaining!!